# How to upgrade Jenkins to newer version

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins version 1.466 on Windows OS 2003. I would like to upgrade it to newer version can some one provide me the more details how this can be done. What are the steps i need to follow. I have around 100 + plugins installed and 6 build salves linked to our Jenkins Master server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You
SA

Comment: Did you do a simple web search before posting? This is a simple procedure that is very well documented.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the inbuilt update option on the mananagement page `http://<yourserver>/manage`